# Node.js/express deployment to different environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, express

I'm writing a node.js app using express on the server.  I'm also using handlebars and precompiling templates for use on the client.  When running the app locally, I want to to keep each of the client source files (models, views, util files) in tact for debugging purposes, but when I deploy, I want the templates to be compiled and all of the client js files merged and minified to be served in one request.  Before I write my own deploy scripts to do this, are there any existing frameworks/utilities that accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an asset manager

https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets

https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager

https://github.com/Cowboy-coder/bundle-up

https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.packer